# Не читаются строчки в текстовом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь прочитать каждую строчку по отдельности в текстовом файле.
Но в результате выдает пустую строчку.

Например:

```py
ids_db=open(file_name, 'r')
for line in ids_db:
    lines_count+=1
for i in range(lines_count):
    id_from_db=ids_db.readline()
    get_friends_list=vk.friends.get(user_id=id_from_db, order='id', v=5.103)
    print(id_from_db)
```

Comment: Питон может сразу итерировать строки в файле.

Comment: так все же почему питон не читает строчки

Comment: @мэрочун Потому, что open() создаёт итератор. А итератор итерируется один раз. Когда он заканчивается, то выдаёт ошибку StopIteration. Он проитерировался у вас при подсчёте строк. А после кидает StopIteration при каждой попытке получить следующее значение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше так:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as ids_db:
    for id_from_db in ids_db.readlines():
        get_friends_list=vk.friends.get(user_id=id_from_db, order='id', v=5.103)
        print(id_from_db)
```

Answer (score 6):

Вы столкнулись с проблемой известной как `"exhausted iterator"`.

File descriptor (указатель файла) `ids_db` - является итерируемым объектом. После первого цикла:

```
for line in ids_db:
    lines_count+=1
```

вы проитерировались до конца файла. Во втором цикле вы пытаетесь читать файл в тот момент когда указатель файла указывает на его конец.

В общем случае можно заставить указатель указывать на начало файла:

```
ids_db.seek(0)
```

**НО** гораздо эффективнее проходить / итерировать по файлу всего **один раз**:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as ids_db:
    for line_no, id_from_db in enumerate(ids_db, 1):
        get_friends_list=vk.friends.get(user_id=id_from_db, order='id', v=5.103)
        print(f"parsed line [{line_no}] -> id: [{id_from_db}]")
```